# Should I aggregate data or not?

Tags: modeling, data-transformation

I have the power consumption of 1000 companies in a city for the last one year. The granularity is by day. What I need to predict is the **TOTAL** power consumption of these companies for the next month by day.

I am confused whether should I build models on the **aggregated** power consumption of these companies. If I aggregate these companies, I will lose a lot of detail like the trend of different companies. Could you please give me any advice?

Comment: You are asking much too broad a question about your analysis strategy. Could you find something specific to ask?

Comment: Why would you aggregate? It seems like there is no good reason to, except maybe for computational issues?

Comment: Mixed effects model? It's the in-between of fit all companies individually and fit all companies together.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by aggregate? Do you mean collapse the 1000 companies into one, or do you mean collapse the 365/6 days into one, or both?

Comment: @mdewey OP means aggregating across companies, not across days.

Comment: @Mark White So should I build 1000 individual models for each company? The trend of different company is quite different.